# General Database Design for Authorization & Authentication Webservice that use in all range of application

Tags: sql, database

See this picture please (**My Authentication & Authorization Database Design**)

[image: My Authentication & Authorization Database Design]

All tables are good! Except **USER** (USER table have different scenarios in different applications - USER can be Personnel, Employee, ...)

I want to have a web service and a general Authentication & Authorization in one database so I must add a table for ApplicationName and add ApplicationID field to all tables, it's not a problem

But my problem is **user table** in different applications **user table is different**

How I can manage user table for general purpose for different applications and different necessaries?

Must I insert all users records of all applications into web service user table?

Comment: Although its quite late , but would be nice if you post your answer as i am also in a similiar situation.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest having a centralized table (`` `accounts` `` or `` `users` `` are good names) which assigns an `id` to all personnel and employees alike. Then merely reference the user's id in your `` `personnel` `` or `` `employee` `` tables so you can give each user whatever table structures they need. For easier queries, you can add checkbox-like columns to the centralized table identifying whether the user exists in other tables etc.